# Is there some nuance between anyone and anybody?

Tags: word-meaning

I've always used them interchangeably according to my mood.

But are there any rare cases where they aren't interchangeable or have a slightly different meaning?

Answer (score 2):

> Anyone and anybody have no difference in meaning. Anybody is a little
>   less formal than anyone. Anyone is used more in writing than anybody.

[Anyone, anybody and anything (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/anyone-anybody-or-anything)

Comment: so is the case with someone/somebody, everyone/everybody and no one/nobody

Comment: yes, I think you could say the same about those three word pairs.